# Custom sorting in shell

Tags: shell, sorting

I would like to have custom order for a sorting: 'D','R' -> 'I' -> 'W','X' and 'Z'.  That is, 'D' and 'R' are equal and sort before 'I'; and 'W', 'X' and 'Z' are equal and sort after 'I'.

Input:

```
123D123
234R111
333I333
111W111
222X222
111Z111
```

The sorting will be on the 4th character, and then followed by a sorting from 5th to 7th characters.

The expected output would be:

```
234R111
123D123
333I333
111W111
111Z111
222X222
```

Comment: Please check that I'm interpreting the alphabetic sort correctly.  The secondary sort isn't making sense to me; how does `W111` sort after `X222`?  Under any plausible interpretation I've thought of, the X-line should be last in the output after the Z-line and X-line; the order of the Z-line and X-line is indeterminate.

Comment: Sorry for my typo. Question revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste <(cut -c 4-7 file | tr 'RWX' 'DZZ') <(cat file) | sort -k 1,1 | awk '{print $2}'

234R111
123D123
333I333
111W111
111Z111
222X222
```

Explanation: create a key where R=D and W=X=Z, sort by key, discard the key